# Trim middle name to middle inital

Tags: excel, trim

I am looking to change a name format using a TRIM formula.  Currently I have
Last, First Middle

People without an middle name are simply displayed as
Last, First
These names can stay as is, but the formula needs to be formatted to allow these names to not be edited.

I would like to trim this to 
Last, First M

Thank you in advance.

Currently I have found the following but I am having issues reverse engineering the formula.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",REPT(" ",LEN(B2))),LEN(B2),LEN(B2))&" "&LEFT(B2,FIND(",",B2)-1))
```

Comment: Goggle **LEFT,RIGHT, and MID**

Comment: Not super useful.  I cannot find this exact example unless I want all the information in different cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following, assuming single spaces. If more than single space you will need to replace with single spaces.

```
=LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2,FIND(",",B2)+2)+1)
```

More than single space:

```
= LEFT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(32)," ")),FIND(" ",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(32)," ")),FIND(",",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(32)," "))  )+2)+1)
```

If no middle name perhaps simply wrap in an IFERROR

```
=IFERROR( LEFT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(32)," ")),FIND(" ",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(32)," ")),FIND(",",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(32)," "))  )+2)+1),TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(32)," ")))
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have updated my question as I had one to many commas.

Comment: Ok. Did you try the above?

Comment: I did.  But with the additional comma I had in the original question it does not work.  If I do change the original name to last, Fist, Middle it works well.  But as it is actually formatted as Last, First Middle it does not work.  It returns #VALUE!

Comment: That works well for most names.  Now I need to format it to work with people who have no middle name.

Comment: Please state all your requirements in the question up front.

Comment: @phifer2088: as QHarr suggested please update your question properly. You can't come up with new question every time someone try to answer your question.

Comment: The question has been updated.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: QHarr, Thank you.  The IFERROR function worked well!